# Is there a way to recover a database(.db or .mdb file) from just the jdbc database url?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have a jdbc url and login credentials as shown below :-

```
jdbc:sqlserver://${my_server:my_port_number};DatabaseName=${my_database_name}
```

Is it possible to **recover the entire database from this(.mdb file** in this case)?

Comment: Have you check something like https://www.mdb.repair/ ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about database recovery belongs on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No, that's not possible. A "database" in SQL Server is way more than just a URL.

Comment: A MDB file is an access database. Seems to me you have some confusion over what database engine you are using and how to recover or restore a sql server database. The latter is a dba function and is off-topic for SO.